# What is the format string for the Ticks of a DateTime?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

How can I format a `DateTime` with `ToString(string format)` to get the [`Ticks` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8) of it?

The [Custom date and time format strings on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) doesn't detail a format for ticks. Is it really not possible to specify ticks in the format string?

i.e. where ticks gives you a value such as:

```
> DateTime.Now.Ticks
637014563963906371
```

I would like to be able to do

```
> DateTime.Now.ToString("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq")
"637014563963906371"
```

where `qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq` is the mystery format string.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()`???

Comment: Why not `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 16)`

Comment: You mean like "if I wanted the year out of a datetime I would use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")` " and you want the command to give you the ticks?

Comment: There is no format specifier for Ticks - and there's no need for one since you can always use the code suggested in the comment by ThePerplexedOne.

Comment: It's hard to understand why `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()` isn't enough, but you can always make your own extension.

Comment: @ZoharPeled; "No need". Well it's a helper, it would be nice. Just as you could do the same with all other parts of the DateTime object.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one - [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) lists all the applicable format strings for a datetime and that page doesn't mention anything you can pass `DateTime.ToString()` and have it return you the ticks. If you want your ticks as a string you'll have to go as per the comments:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
```

This can, of course accept format strings of its own operating as a number, for example if you wanted it in hexadecimal:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
```

If you wanted it as part of a larger (interpolated) string, padded to 20 characters:

```
$"Ticks now, padded with leading zeroes to 20 wide is: {DateTime.Now.Ticks:D20}"
```

etc.

Note: you wrote 16 `q` in your "mystery format string" but ticks is already 18 digits, so unless you're trying to truncate it, bear this 18 digit minimum in mind